# Altgr randomly stops working on windows 8

Tags: windows-8, keyboard, alt

usually AltGr Works fine on my computer but latelly it stops working. I can still use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> but it's a pain as I need it to write {} and I'm a c# programmer :S

Any idea on what can happen? If I reboot the laptop everything Works fine. It's not a failure of the key itself becasue when I press it the menus get the _ drawn, so the keyboard is sending the message to the OS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your keyboard layout? Do you have any other layouts enabled?

Comment: I already checked the layout and it's ok. I have two layouts but almost always I use just one. The issue has stopped a few minutes ago without restarting, It has come and gone.

Comment: You say computer, I assume laptop, because my first test would be replacing it.. but somehow I have the feeling you lack that choice.

Comment: @NickW: yeah, that's an option but somehow the key is working even when it don't do its complete function. When I press it the menus show the _ so the keyboard is sensing the key press ... :S

Comment: I'd try swapping keyboards, just to be sure. Just as an aside, it isn't a bluetooth keyboard is it? I've had issues with interference make my keyboard do very strange things.

Comment: No it's not, I had also that kind of problems with the wireless keyboard but this one is the physical one. It hasn't failed on the last week so I'll give it a chance. Anyway thanks!

Comment: This happens to me too, randomly stops working, I used to have another language installed  but this still happens after i removed the language, sometimes a restart fixes it and another times it fixes its self.

Comment: Well, i just confirmed is not my keyboard, AltGr is currently disabled locally on my machine but if I use Remote Desktop AltGr works on the remote desktop window.

Comment: For me the problem was just that there had been a change in "Text service and input language" in Windows. I fixed it by removing any shortcuts.

Comment: I can confirm that this is still a problem in windows 10.

Answer (score 169, accepted):

There are many blog posts out there, which try to explain what the issue could be. Many times specific programs are the cause of the problem.

For me it was a `Windows Remote Desktop` connection I had running, that prevented the key from working. I didn't have to close it, just opening the window and clicking anywhere inside it somehow made my [AltGR] key work again!

EDIT: It seems to the related to the full-screen mode of RDP.

Just try to close all your applications one by one to find out what could be the cause.

Comment: Maybe I had a WRD active ... I don't remember. I'll check this the next time. Thanks!

Comment: Works for me after closing all RDP sessions, thanks.

Comment: I had a remote desktop session running fullscreen on other monitor and that was causing the issue. Minimizing the remote desktop window was enough to solve the issue. The problem does not occur always when remote desktop is fullscreen.

Comment: It just happened to me (Winows 7). I noticed it in Eclipse, but it did not work in other programs either (like the system Run... dialog). I had a RDP window running, so I clicked inside it, tried to type to the remote system and now AltGr worked. Then I went back to a local program in there it worked too. Bizzare...

Comment: Same thing with Virtual PC and Eclipse... weird!

Comment: Closing remote desktop sessions worked for me too.

Comment: Wow, I would have never figured that out. Thanks!!

Comment: Worked for me. Really crazy, but at least for me it was enough to click on the remote desktop window and then click an open program in the remote desktop. After that it worked again everywhere, without rebooting or closing anything.

Comment: Visual Studio and Hyper V remote connection, too.

Comment: That is odd, just clicking on RDC window and come back to my desktop is indeed working. I left RDC open all night and saw that ALTGR was working like ALT. Thanks for the solution :)

Comment: Why on earth is this happening? I can use my altgr again. Thanks!

Comment: Wtf Microsoft ... I'm on Windows 10 and closing RDP worked - one should think it would be fixed by now ... sigh.

Comment: Saved my day :)

Comment: This problem can also occur when you have an RDP session inside another RDP session. Disconnecting from the inner session fixed it for me.

Answer (score 11):

Here it turned out to be a running VirtualBox-instance that had tampered with my keyboard setup. After shifting focus to the VM and back to the editor the AltGr-key worked as expected.

I'm running Windows 7 SP1, so AltGr acting as Alt is a problem not only on Windows 8.

Comment: It was the cause of my problem too. As I use the VM to run a debian server, I turned off the GUI like stated there: http://www.without-brains.net/blog/2011/05/06/running-a-headless-virtualbox-in-windows/ it also increased performence a little bit.

Comment: Me too. Annoying how a user mode application (with half a dozen drivers, no doubt) messes up something as essential as users keyboard layout, without Windows even suspecting it or issuing a  warning to the user of said layout.

Answer (score 10):

For me, it was caused by Hyper-V (Microsoft virtualization). When I go to virtual machine, press <kbd>AltGr</kbd> it works. Return to desktop, works again!

Comment: I had the same issue and focusing to Windows Phone emulator running in the background fixed it.

Comment: Windows 7 virtual machine triggered the problem for me, and I had already closed it. But activating a linux VM and hitting AltGr there also fixed the issue, so it doesn't require correct OS to revert the problem.

Answer (score 3):

My problem with this key was sometimes when I am **in** a remote desktop session. As in, not a problem on the host. I am seeing the problem on the client, in the remote session.

I tried the following - without luck:

- Switching and clicking on the remote desktop session: **Didn't work.**
- Minimizing the remote desktop session: **Didn't work.**
- Restarting the remote desktop session: **Didn't work,** it just re-attaches to the existing session - which still has the issue.

**But, minimizing all application windows in the remote desktop session and then restoring (maximizing) the window where I needed the @ key it works**.

I am actually writing this entry in the remote desktop session, and the @ key works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

The questioner have a laptop, so this is not probably answer for him/her. But nevertheless:

One possible reason of AltGr problems is Gigabyte EasyTune. It adds some own shortcuts to keyboard (or something else), which causes the problem.

Atleast with nordic keyboard maps: it causes problems with '@' [AltGr+2] and '€' [AltGr+5].

With Win8.1 solution was: uninstalling of EasyTune.