# Alt and AltGr key randomly stop working on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, keyboard

Alt and AltGr usually work well but sometimes, for no reason they stop working. Restarting the computer doesn't work. I checked the keyboard language. I checked if I have one of these programs running in the background (List of known programs blocking Altgr):

```
-Remote Desktop Connection 
-Windows XP Mode (Virtual PC)
-EasyTune
-VMWare vCenter
-mRemote
-VirtualBox
-Ditto
-Unknown wmp (winamp?) plugin
-Visual Studio 2010 (an add-in perhaps?)
```

I have a 2015 Acer Aspire with Windows 8.1

Is anyone aware of a different problem that can cause this symptom?

Comment: What are you using them for?

Comment: coding python.
macros on sublime text.

Comment: see http://superuser.com/questions/602067/altgr-randomly-stops-working-on-windows-8