# Windows: Why does the Alt Gr key does not work when an RDP session is running?

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, remote-desktop

I came across some really strange behavior in Windows 7. I usually have open a remote desktop connection to another Windows (Win 7 or 10) machine. Nevertheless, I mainly work on the local machine. Everything, including the <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> key works perfectly. Now let's say I lock my PC by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and unlock it again, the <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> key just does not work anymore. I need to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to the Remote Desktop Window, then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> back to some local program like some browser and - voilá - it works again.

This is a problem as some characters on a German keyboard can only be accessed by using the <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> modifier key. When entering passwords I don't usually see what characters I type, so this causes failed login attempts.

Note that I already completely re-installed Windows on both the remote machine as well as the local machine and it does not seem to depend on which remote machine I am connected to. (However, I cannot tell if this also happens when connecting to remote machines running other OSes.) And, of course, when I am not connected to any RDP session, I don't have any issues with that key.

While researching on this issue I stumbled upon this link, unfortunately it does not provide a solution:
https://forum.devolutions.net/topic9714-altgr-key-disabled-by-rdm.aspx

Some (German) Microsoft help page suggested to switch the "Apply Windows key combinations" in the RDP settings to "On this computer" - however, it does not change anything.

Any further suggestions?

Comment: If you use a different keyboard layout, does the right ALT key, work then?

Comment: I suppose, if anyone knew the answer to this, Microsoft might actually find it in them to fix this apparently long-standing bug.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Altgr randomly stops working on windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/602067/altgr-randomly-stops-working-on-windows-8)

Answer (score 1):

I view it as a behavior which can be called a defect from some viewpoint. I am not sure if there is any solution to that. Maybe you can try with Slovak keyboard layout, it has all the German characters (placed differently, and for example **ö** might require pressing dead key <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>, <kbd>o</kbd> but they are all there) because I do not remember any issues with <kbd>AltGr</kbd> on that keyboard layout.

Another workaround is to click accessibility icon on login screen (or press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> for the same action) and enable On-screen keyboard from displayed menu. Then you can access desired characters by clicking on that on-screen keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

where the bug is still present!

Windows 10, same issue. I use the Slovenian keyboard layout.

1. The issue happens every now and then (always when RDP is used). Did not notice a pattern.
2. I resolve it by going to the RDP window, and there pressing and releasing one after another: SHIFT, CONTROL, ALT, AltGr (sometimes also ESC for a good measure)
3. Alternatively you can press CTRL and ALT (the left one) at the same time, this is same as AltGr. So instead of AltGR+X you use Ctrl+Alt+X. This way you do not have to go to RDP as in point 2.

(the idea from point 2 is also mentioned in the forum linked in the question)

(there are millions of post about this issue on the web, including stack overflow; I'll try to merge them or at least notice the admins)